# Why is Rendered Viewport Shading not working correctly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

When I enable viewport shading rendered mode, it appears that its not rendering my scene properly. Everything appears to be a shade of grey and its hard to make out any shapes.

I am trying to cast some lighting within a cylinder as per a youtube tutorial, however when I go to rendered mode, it appears nothing like it does within the youtube video. I am a total newb at blender and its possible a setting that should be on is not. I have tried to render this scene on a different and better computer, and I get the exact same results, even on a new scene entirely!

I have a point light inside the cylinder which doesnt look how its supposed to, and I have a basic material selected with a Cloud texture.[image]

It appears the render mode itself is not working correctly, as creating a new scene has the same effect. This is through Eevee.

Anyone know what is going on here??

[image: Here is what my scene looks like in Solid shading mode.]

[image: And here is what it looks like in Rendered shading mode.]

Comment: did you apply materials to your object?

Comment: Make sure that you have proper lighting set up in your scene (lamps or perhaps an HDRI). Additionally you need to create a material for your object.

Comment: Both of these are included in the scene.

Comment: Alright I figured it out, turns out the video tutorial i was watching had some presets enabled that a rookie would not have enable right off the bat. My issue was the lighting was not appearing how it was in the tutorial and the reason why mine appeared different was due to shaders. Go figure. Thanks everyone